# Помогите пожалуйста настроить правильный редирект на без www в htaccess на сервере Apache

Tags: .htaccess, apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.rvsgroup.com.ua$
RewriteRule (.*) http://rvsgroup.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Пробовал этот, не работает.
Затем этот:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rvsgroup\.com.ua $ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rvsgroup.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Наверное где-то ошибся в экранировании. Или нет? Подскажите пожалуйста) Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1200891/387248

Comment: Иии?) Что это дает?)